# I can't remove a google classroom course using GAS

Tags: google-classroom

I have been trying to remove a course from my google classroom account. I have the ID and was trying to create a simple function, then I was going to create another function to delete my other classes.

This is the code:

```
function deleteOneCourse() {
  const idclasse = '383075820272';
  Classroom.Courses.remove(idclasse)
  
}
```

When I run the code this message comes up:

> GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to classroom.courses.delete
> failed with error: Precondition check failed. deleteOneCourse @
> Code.gs:58

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Does using [API explorer](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses/delete?apix=true) work?